# Checking the Windows SDK version for remote hosted Azure Agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've built a C++ application in Visual Studio 2019. Now, I want to build it in Azure using remote-hosted agents. When I tried to build it, however, it says:

> The Windows SDK version 10.0.14393 was not found

I checked the Windows version and it says:

> Microsoft Windows Server 2016 10.0.14393

So I assume the agent will use this SDK? How can I check this?

I looked at [the documentation for GitHub virtual environments](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2016-Readme.md), but there is no information on the SDK installed.

The error message is:

```
Starting: Build debug version
==============================================================================
Task         : MSBuild
Description  : Build with MSBuild
Version      : 1.188.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild
==============================================================================
"D:\a\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.188.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [16.0,17.0) -latest -format json
"D:\a\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.188.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [16.0,17.0) -products Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools -latest -format json
"D:\a\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.188.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [15.0,16.0) -latest -format json
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" "D:\a\1\s\spaceShooter\spaceShooter.vcxproj" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.188.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=|SolutionDir=D:\a\1\s\spaceShooter"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.188.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"  /p:platform="x86" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_f74fab68-3934-42f1-834a-f50351da5a8a_build_2_0"
Build started 9/1/2021 10:59:53 AM.
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.targets(46,5): Error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 10.0.14393 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution".
Project "D:\a\1\s\spaceShooter\spaceShooter.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.targets(46,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 10.0.14393 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [D:\a\1\s\spaceShooter\spaceShooter.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\spaceShooter\spaceShooter.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"D:\a\1\s\spaceShooter\spaceShooter.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(_CheckWindowsSDKInstalled target) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.targets(46,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 10.0.14393 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [D:\a\1\s\spaceShooter\spaceShooter.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.98
##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```